# Why The Torah is in scrolls in modern times when books are more convenient

Tags: minhag, sefer-torah

Why The Torah is in scrolls in modern times when books are more convenient to hold and read ?

I can understand that in olden days it was convenient to carry and read on scrolls as the Torah was often written on fragile materials, but now when good quality of paper and books are available then why we use the traditional styled scrolls for torah ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use a torah scroll for the torah service because that is the halacha (see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22573/472) citing Rama (OC 143:2)).  Just because there's a more "convenient" format doesn't mean we're free to change how we perform public worship.  (I mean, why not skip books entirely and project the text onto the wall, in that case?  But we don't, even on weekdays when there'd be no melacha.)

We do use books (such as chumashim) for other purposes -- for study, reference, and non-liturgical reading.  But to say a blessing for a public torah reading, halacha requires a kosher torah scroll.

Comment: For SAM, now I understand, it seems there are special rules for writing and reading Torah

Comment: For Monica Cellio, Now i understand that, at the time of prayers some selected special portions of Torah are been used, therefore the scrolls are more convenient, and it is also halacha,. regarding your idea of projecting the torah passage on wall, in my opinion it does not seems appropriate for the respect of the torah, as I too respect the Torah.

Comment: @Ishrat I'm not arguing for projection either; I think that would be a terrible idea.  I brought it up because it's one place an argument based on convenience leads.

Comment: at Monica Cellio, Sorry I had misunderstood.