# Torah service without a chazzan

Tags: torah-reading

Is there a special name for a congregant who follows the Torah text in the actual scroll with a yad at the bimah while someone stands next to him/her and chants the text from a chumash (when there is no trained Torah reader available who can chant directly from the Torah scroll). That congregant doesn't need to be an oleh and get an aliyah (although they can), their job is to follow the text carefully with a yad while another congregant chants it out loud from a chumash. I'm just wondering if there is a special term describing this job.

I saw this situation at a service where there was a minyan but no one knew how to chant the Torah from the scroll. So one person used a chumash instead to chant the text out loud but another congregant quietly followed the text with a yad in the actual scroll. They tried to make up for the fact that no one was able to chant it from the scroll - the text was sung out loud from the chumash and at the same time quietly traced with a yad in the Torah scroll.

Comment: Is this person repeating the reading from inside the Torah scroll? Otherwise I don't understand what they are doing up there

Comment: Question isn't clear. Seems to be describing the job of a 'somekh' who stands at the side of the reader aiding the latter with the musical notes (and pronunciation of words, if necessary).

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. You may want to clarify where you have seen this custom  and/or if the person following from the scroll is actually reading it out loud.  In traditional congregations, the Torah is read out loud from the actual scroll, though, in instances where the reader may be unfamiliar with the text, there may be someone on hand assisting him quietly from a chumash.

Comment: Generally, there wouldn't be a title for something that has no halachic or minhag precedence. What you described seems  to fit that group. Congregational Torah reading must be done from a kosher Torah scroll. Otherwise, there is no mitzvah being accomplished other than that of studying Torah which does not require a congregation and can be done individually. Seems that you've essentially described a chevruta.

Comment: I have seen a case where there was not a minyan on Shabbat where they took out the Torah scroll and covered it, and read from a Chumash instead.  The mitzvah of public reading was not accomplished, but you might say a "lesser" mitzvah of Torah study was still done.  The situation Rebekah describes seems similar.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. I saw this situation at a service where there was a minyan but no one knew how to chant the Torah from the scroll. So one person used a chumash instead to chant the text out loud but another congregant quietly followed the text with a yad in the actual scroll. They tried to make up for the fact that no one was able to chant it from the scroll - the text was sung out loud from the chumash and at the same time quietly traced with a yad in the Torah scroll.

Comment: Related: "[Can a public Torah reading be done by repeating words and trope as read by another](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48462/1368)"? "[Can a chumash be used for a public torah reading](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22572/1368)"?

Comment: It sounds like you did it backwards. I'll see if I can locate the halachic source in O.C. I believe he says that in such situations, the person should read from the Chumash quietly and the "main" person should read loudly from the Torah scroll. The point is that the mitzvah of congregational reading is accomplished specifically when read from a scroll. Of course, I can't post an answer until this question is reopened.