# Why not read missing words (in Esther) from a printed copy?

Tags: halacha, purim, megillat-esther

*Kitzur Shulchan Aruch* 141:19:

> צבור שאין להם מגילה כשרה כדינה מכל מקום אם היא כתובה כהלכתה רק שחסרים איזה תיבות באמצעה כיון שלא חסר בה ענין אחד שלם יכולין לקרות מתוכה עם הברכות והטעות יקרא הקורא בעל פה או יאמר לפניו בלחש מתוך החומש

In my own loose translation:

> A community that has no valid *m'gila*: Nonetheless, if it's written on parchment properly, but [the problem is that] it's missing some words in the middle, since no entire topic is missing, they can read from it, with [recitation of] the blessings [before and after reading]. The reader should recite the missing part by heart or someone should say it quietly it to him from a printed book [so he knows what to say].

Why shouldn't he read it from a printed book, himself? That seems easier than having someone read it to him quietly.

Comment: Speculation on some possibilities: 1. The KS"A was not halachically excluding this possibility; he was just mentioning the most common scenario, since the reader might want to keep his eyes on the scroll so that he can more easily read the words that are there and keep track of his place. 2. He was halachically excluding reading from a book because (a.) it could be a מראית העין problem, with people thinking that it is acceptable to read from a printed מגילה in general, or (b.) the reader might get so caught up reading from the printed מגילה that he would read an ענין שלם.

Comment: possibly related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22573/759