# If one hears the Megillah read from a non-scroll version, has he completed the mitzvah?

Tags: halacha, purim, megillat-esther

If one hears the Megillah read from a chumash or the like, is he yotze the mitzvah b'dieved?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53310

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Magen Avraham* 690:6 implies very strongly that one cannot fulfil his obligation by hearing the *m'gila* from a printed book. He's commenting on the *Shulchan Aruch*, which says:

> Someone holding in hand a *m'gila* that is not valid should not read with the designated [reader] but be quiet and listen.

*Magen Avraham* comments (in part, citing *Bes Yosef*):

> Because [if he reads along then] someone who hears him may pay attention to this reader [from an invalid *m'gila*] and not to the designated [reader].

Thus, listening to someone reading it from a printed version is insufficient.

*Magen Avraham* 691:10 implies the same, perhaps even stronger. He's commenting on the *Shulchan Aruch*, which says:

> If there's no valid *m'gila*, read it from a *chumash* without [saying] the benedictions [before and after].

*Magen Avraham* comments (in part, citing *Bes Yosef*):

> That's because some say one fulfills his obligation in that way *bish'as had'chak* [ ≈ if one's under pressure]. But that's specifically if it's made as a scroll… but has an invalidation; however, one does not fulfill his obligation using **our** *chumashim* according to anyone.

I don't know for certain what his "our *chumashim*" were precisely, but presumably they were something like ours.

Interestingly, *Magen Avraham* 143:2 says that if there's no *sefer Tora* then one should read from an "our" *chumash*, not because it fulfills any obligation according to anyone, but "so that the law of reading not be forgotten", yet he does not say this about the *m'gila*. I don't know why.

Comment: Seemingly his Chumashim were hand printed instead of laser/inkjet printed. Though that probably helps your case.

Answer (score 3):

It appears from this [site](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/bringing-babies-and-small-children-to-megillah-reading) that the answer is no, one is not yotzei (CYLOR, of course).

In the course of the discussion there was brought up the idea of "if someone missed words can he say them from his own printed book" and to support this, someone said, "I heard otherwise from one of the biggest poskim in Yerushalayim. He said that if one misses a few words, they can read it themselves from their sefer until they catch up... I asked a shaila afterwards to see if I was yotzei and the psak was that I was, as long as I hadn't read more than a certain percentage of it (which I cannot recall right now)."

But this position (though anecdotally supported) was argued.

I haven't checked the sources, but the following is cited there:

"One is not allowed to lain Megillah from a sefer (non Klaf). However just like a Megillah that is missing some letters or even words (or even an entire Pasuk) is still valid (SA 690:3), and one can read those letters and words by heart (ibid), one can also be read the megillah Via Shomaya K'One from the Klaf, and read "some words" Ba'al Peh. (catching up to where the Koreh is), as long as Rov is read from the Klaf.

However, an entire "Inyan" can not be left out of the Megillah, so it can not be read Ba'al Pah, so it can't be made up either."

So it seems that a klaf is required.

This [site](http://www.eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=48&cat=7&newsletter=855&article=3257) writes that one may make up parts from the printed text, but not the entirety:

> We see from here that reading a minority of the Megilla without a kosher klaf is valid. However, the Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chayim 690:3) says that this is only b’di’eved (i.e., one who already read it so, need not repeat it, or, if he has no other megilla, he can use that one – Mishna Berura ad loc.:8)